# Error in installing Open-CV with eclipse

Tags: android

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'CDT Builder' on project 'org.opencv.samples.tutorial3.Sample3Native'.
Internal error building project org.opencv.samples.tutorial3.Sample3Native configuration Default
java.lang.NullPointerException
Internal error building project org.opencv.samples.tutorial3.Sample3Native configuration Default
java.lang.NullPointerException

help me